# Render large and clickable grid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, optimization, drawing

I'm trying to create a large grid which cells have drawn a clickable (click event) ellipsis.

I'm using a Canvas as a parent and adding Ellipses to it Children List but when I try to render 100x100 ellipsis, it lags.

I've tried rendering them with the DrawingVisual and DrawingContext but then, they are not clickable and I won't be able to store ellipsis properties (color, stroke...).

Current code to render the Ellipsis

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.grid.Cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < this.grid.Rows; j++) {
        SolidColorBrush fillBrush = Brushes.Red;
        SolidColorBrush strokeBrush = Brushes.Blue;

        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse() {
            Width = this.grid.Radius,
            Height = this.grid.Radius,
            Fill = fillBrush,
            Stroke = strokeBrush,
            StrokeThickness = 2
        };

        Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, (this.grid.Radius * j) + (j * this.grid.Margin));
        Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, (this.grid.Radius * i) + (i * this.grid.Margin));

        children.Add(ellipse);
        parent.Children.Add(ellipse);
    }
}
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to be able to render the ellipses differently, e.g., should the appearance change if the cursor is over one, or the user is clicking on one?

Comment: I'm searching that the user can click everyone and then the clicked one changes it color, that's why I render them one by one, but I don't care how they are rendered or how they are drawn

Comment: Can you describe your use case in a bit more detail?  There are a bunch of questions that come to mind, but it might be easier to just tell us what you're going to use this for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting a limitation of what WPF can render with it's framework.  Ellipses, or all drawing objects, are objects with quite a few properties and events on them.  Rendering 10,000 will cause you to lag.

Your best bet is to use DrawingContext and create your own methods that are simpler, and create your own methods to track when something is clicked.

Comment: With DrawingContext, can I "redraw" just one ellipse, or I'll need to redraw all element?

Comment: You should be able to use DirtyRect to redraw just one area, but it gets more complex

Comment: Could you add a link to DirtyRect? I can't find it on google xd

Comment: I've made it. I can render a large images without lag but I can't make it clickable. I'm using a List to store all "Ellipsis" (position and color) and when I click I check the position, and redraw all with correct color but checking the position last for minutes.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of efficiency, the most 'lightweight' solution would probably be to render a single ellipse to a `RenderTargetBitmap`, then have a custom control paint a rectangle with a tiled `ImageBrush` to repeat the same ellipse over and over.  The nice part about using a `RenderTargetBitmap` is that you can let the developer plug in *any* visual element to tile; it needn't be an ellipse.

You'll need a method to translate between screen coordinates and `(column, row)` pairs.  You'll know the size of the ellipse's bitmap, so that part should be pretty easy.

To handle subtle changes when the mouse is hovering over or pressing down on an ellipse, you should push some clip geometry into your `DrawingContext` to draw everywhere *except* the region containing the ellipse under the cursor.  Then pop the mask and draw a rectangle with an *alternate* `ImageBrush` containing the ellipse in a hover/pressed state.

To handle clicking, you'll need to write some custom hit testing logic.  Basically, you'll want something like this:

```
private bool TryHitTest(Point p, out int column, out int row)
{
    column = -1;
    row = -1;

    if (p.X < 0 || p.X > ActualWidth || p.Y < 0 || p.Y > ActualHeight)
        return false;

    var image = /* your ellipse bitmap */;
    if (image == null)
        return false;

    var tileWidth = image.Width;
    var tileHeight = image.Height;

    var x = (int)(p.X % tileWidth);
    var y = (int)(p.Y % tileHeight);

    // If you want pixel-perfect hit testing, check the alpha channel.
    // Otherwise, skip this check.
    if (image.GetPixel(x, y).A == 0)
        return false;

    column = (int)Math.Floor(p.X / tileWidth);
    row = (int)Math.Floor(p.Y / tileHeight);

    return true;
}
```

If you want pixel-perfect hit testing, you should copy your `RenderTargetBitmap` into a `WriteableBitmap` and then use the **WriteableBitmapEx** library to fetch the color at the hit-tested coordinate and check whether the alpha is non-zero.

To provide click event notification, you'll need to handle the usual mouse events:

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = CaptureMouse();
}

protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsMouseCaptured &&
        TryHitTest(e.GetPosition(this), out var column, out var row))
    {
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
        e.Handled = true;

        //
        // Raise 'TileClick' event with 'column' and 'row'. 
        //
    }
}

private (int x, int y) _lastHover;

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TryHitTest(e.GetPosition(this), out var x, out var y);

    if (_lastHover.x != x || _lastHover.y != y)
        InvalidateVisual();

    _lastHover = (x, y);
}
```

---

#### Addendum: Rendering

Since there was some confusion about how I described rendering to rectangles, let me clarify: I was not talking about painting a `Rectangle` element.  The idea was to create a custom control that performs its own rendering, and draws rectangle *geometry* painted with the tiled image brush.  Your `OnRender` method would look something like this:

```cs
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    base.OnRender(dc);

    var regularBrush  = /* regular cell tiled brush */;
    var hoverBrush =  /* hovered cell brush */;

    var fullBounds = new Rect(/* full bounds */);
    var hoverBounds = new Rect(/* bounds of hovered cell */);

    var hasHoveredCell = /* is there a hovered cell? */;
    if (hasHoveredCell)
    {
        // Draw everywhere *except* the hovered cell.
        dc.PushClip(
            Geometry.Combine(
                new RectangleGeometry(fullBounds),
                new RectangleGeometry(hoverBounds),
                GeometryCombineMode.Exclude,
                Transform.Identity));
    }

    dc.DrawRectangle(regularBrush , null, fullBounds);

    if (hasHoveredCell)
    {
        // Pop the clip and draw the hovered cell.
        dc.Pop();
        dc.DrawRectangle(hoverBrush, null, hoverBounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've done the custom control and the mouse control for it, so when I click down in an element I can retrieve the element position (col, row) but no idea how to repaint _that_ element and just it.

Comment: Paint everything, on two rectangles (small for the hovered cell, large for the rest).  For the large rectangle, create some clipping geometry by subtracting the small rectangle's geometry form the large one, then push that clip into your DC before drawing the large rectangle. That should draw the 'regular' ellipses everywhere _except_ the hovered cell.  Then draw the hovered cell.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I don't get it. I'm creating a Rectangle (xaml); then I create a DrawingVisual with the base ellipse and I'm rendering this visual into a ImageBrush with the `TileMode = TileMode.Tile` and finally I'm applying this Brush to the xaml rectangle. But now, you say that I should create another rectangle (xaml?) that contains the alternative ellipse and draw it inside the previous context? Can you write the code please? I think I won't get it otherwise.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Misunderstanding: I didn't mean to paint a `Rectangle` element, but to use a `DrawingContext` to draw rectangle geometry.  See the latest addition to my answer.